# Submitting data from HTML form to pdf

Tags: php, html, oop

I want to write data from a HTML form into a PDF document. Here's my code:

(home.php)

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
      NAME:<input type="text" name="name" ><br><br>
      E-mail:<input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
      Submit:<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['name'])){
      echo "fill"."<br><br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['email'])){
      if(empty($_POST['name'])){
        echo "check";
      }
    }   
  }
?>
```

(test.php)

```
<?php
  require('fpdf.php');

  class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Header() {
      $this->SetFont('Helvetica','B',15);
      $this->SetXY(50, 10);
      $this->Cell(0,10,'This is a header',1,0,'C');
    }

    function content() {
      $html = '<table> 
          <tr>
          <td>'.$_POST['name'].'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>'.$_POST['email'].'</td>
          </tr>
          </table> ';
          $this->write($html);
        }

        function Footer() {
          $this->SetXY(100,-15);
          $this->SetFont('Helvetica','I',10);
          $this->Write (5, 'This is a footer');
        }
      }
      $pdf=new PDF();
      $pdf->AddPage();
      $pdf->Output();
    ?>
```

Comment: Is there a problem or a question?

Comment: problem is 

i am not able save data into pdf

Comment: So what error does it give you when you try to accomplish this?

Comment: it simply shows Header and footer section  not content section

Comment: There are many `fpdf` libraries out there. Please provide a link to the one that you're using. I don't believe that `function content()` is proper.

Comment: when im using

function Header()
  {
  $html = '<table> 
   <tr>
   <td>'.$_POST['name'].'</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>'.$_POST['email'].'</td>
   </tr>
   
   </table> ';
   

   $this->Header($_POST['name'], $_POST['email']);

it shows  
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261900 bytes)

Comment: sorry as im new to this site so i dont  know  how to arrange code properly

Comment: shouldnt you $pdf->content() after $pdf->AddPage()? Header and Footer seem to be out of the box functions but any content seems to be something you yourself have to paste after the "AddPage" (but just took a diagional scan over the faq)

Answer (score 0):

```
       by changing libraries name i got  the  answer.
hope yhis will help  you  to.



<?php
require('htmlFPDF/html2fpdf.php');
    $pdf=new HTML2FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $fp = fopen("sample.html","r");

        $strContent = "<table style='width:100%; border=1px solid black;padding:5px;'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <td><h1 style='text-align:center'><b>Your submitted data is</b></h1></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>$_POST[name]</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>$_POST[email]</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Telephone</td>
          <td>$_POST[telephone]</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td>ADDRESS</td>
          <td>$_POST[address]</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Deliver or Pickup</td>
          <td>$_POST[delivery]</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td>Camper Tank</td>
          <td>$_POST[tank_size]</td></tr>
        [16-Sep-14 5:31:48 PM] VIKRANT SHARMA: </thead>
        </table>";

    $pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);
    $pdf->Output('Plastic-data.pdf','D');
        echo "PDF file is generated successfully!";
?>
```